# Meaning of #var="ngModel"

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am creating `login.component.html` and during that time I create an input field then bind it to the `email` variable found in my `login.component.ts`. Originally I had written it as:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" id="email"
       [(ngModel)] = "email" name = "email" required #email="ngModel"/>
```

but continued to receive errors until I changed it to:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" id="email"
       [(ngModel)] = "email" name = "email" required #em="ngModel"/>
```

What exactly is going on at `#em="ngModel"` and why can I only use incredibly specific values?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The syntax you refer to is mentioned in [the form validation docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html), where they explain:

> The template variable (`#name`) has the value `"ngModel"` (always
>   `ngModel`). This gives you a reference to the Angular `NgModel`
>   directive associated with this control that you can use *in the
>   template* to check for control states such as `valid` and `dirty`.

The problem is that you have a property named `email` on your `@Component` class and a [reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars) named `email` in its template. You cannot have both, hence the error you see:

```
Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
```

Renaming either the property or the reference variable (in your case you changed the latter to `em`) fixes the problem. You're not limited to *"incredibly specific values"*, you could have changed to any valid identifier that wasn't also a property.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, is the sole purpose of assigning ngModel to a template reference variable to access the item properties like touched, dirty? Or does it serve any more purpose? Example: just using #em withit ngModel assignment would enable access the value of the item isnt it?

Comment: @variable as it says in the answer, you use this to get access to *the NgModel directive* from the template. Just `#em` would give you access to *the input element*, from which you could indeed get the value.

Comment: @johnsharpe, assigning template ref variable say #f to a form tag will also give access to all form element values? Or do I have to write #f="ngForm"?

Comment: @variable it's unclear to me what you mean, I'd suggest you try it and find out.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue few days back ,when I did R&D on it then i found that

```
 #var="ngModel" exports NgModel into a local variable called "var".
```

Through this we can check **control states** such as **valid** and **dirty** and **touched**